# Python subprocess gives OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, bash, operating-system, subprocess

I'm writing a python script that needs to call a bash script. 
The python script contains variables `a1` and `a2` that need to be passed as arguments to the bash script.
I've imported `subprocess` and am running it like this:

```
subprocess.check_call( ["./test.sh", a1, a2], shell=False)
```

but I am getting an error from this line that

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. 
What should I be doing differently?

Comment: you are trying to call a unix script in windows ?

Comment: UNIX supports the `#!` line, Windows does not.  Your `test.sh` will not have the correct magic number or file association for a Windows executable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' you can call your script like this:

```
subprocess.check_call( ['bash', '-c', './test.sh', a1, a2], shell=False)
```

To have this feature on Windows, you need Windows 10 and you can follow instructions in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Generally speaking, even on unix machines this will be a better approach (even though in most of them .sh files will just execute without running them explicitly in bash)